# Links in Documents in Same Folder

Tags: sharepoint-2007

How do I put website link and a Word document in the same folder?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the "Link to document" content type

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2007/08/sharepoint-adding-hyperlinks-to-doc.html